# How to show the label on R using cut showing the break to infinity

Tags: r

I can't find a solution in R (using data.table) to group data by a custom range (for example, -18, 18-25, ..., 65+) not by a single value.

What I'm using right now:

```
DT[,list(M_Savings=mean(Savings), M_Term=mean(Term)), by=Age] [order (Age)]
```

This gives me the following result:

```
    Age     M_Savings   M_Term
1:  18      6500        5.5 
2:  19      7000        6.2 
3:  20      7200        5.8
...
50: 68      4000        4.2
```

Desirable result:

```
    Age     M_Savings   M_Term
1:  18-25   7450        5.5 
2:  25-30   8320        6.2 
...
50: 65+     3862
```

i know you can use cut for this but how would you be able to show the label 65+?

I'm getting this,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wqv7.png)

but i need this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/437GP.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can give your custom labels in `cut` :

```
library(data.table)

DT[, Age := cut(Age, c(-Inf, 18, 25, 30, ..., 65, Inf), 
                    c('[0-18)', '(18-25]', '(25-30]', ..., '65+'))]

DT[,.(M_Savings=mean(Savings), M_Term=mean(Term)), by=Age][order (Age)]
```

Comment: My `santoku` package is also useful for customizing cut labels.